# Why doesn't Crontab run the command inserted by python script?

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am trying to modify the crontab of the root user through a script of python (main.py).

This script will open the crontab for root user and will modify it inserting a new command to call single.py with a parameter. The command used is not the problem as I have run it from the command line  and it works. When I run the main.py script I can see the new entry when I run the `crontab -l` command. Everything looks correct but it does not work when is the time (nothing has been executed).

Doing some checks, if I execute the `crontab -e` command and I insert the command manually; when I save and close it; it shows: `**crontab: installing new crontab**` and then it works.

main.py:

```
fname = "/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"
f = open(fname,"w+")

f.write("24 19 16 01 * python /home/pi/single.py 2087111972\n")

f.close() # save and close cron file
```

BTW: As this script has to be recursive (it will call itself for rescheduling its execution by modifying the crontab), is there anyway to apply the changes on crontab through the script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restarting cron after changing crontab file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193788/restarting-cron-after-changing-crontab-file)

Comment: The `crontab` command sends a message to `cron` telling it to pick up the changes. If you modify the file directly, it never realizes that it changed.

Comment: Your code completely replaces the crontab. You should use `a` mode when opening to add to it.

Comment: Also, you need to write a newline at the end.

Comment: Also, you should only append that line once, if it isn't already in the crontab file.

Comment: If this is root's crontab, it doesn't need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! As this script has to be recursive (it will call itself for rescheduling its execution by modifying the crontab), is there anyway to apply the changes on crontab through the script?

Comment: This isn't specifically a Python issue, it's generic to whenever you try to edit crontab without using `crontab -e` [What is the risk when editing crontab file without the "crontab -e" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022154/what-is-the-risk-when-editing-crontab-file-without-the-crontab-e-command)

Comment: [python-crontab library](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/)

Comment: Separately, *"this script has to be recursive (it will call itself for rescheduling its execution by modifying the crontab)"* sounds like a bad idea. Why can't you have the scheduled dayofmonth, monthofyear be `* *` instead of 1/16? Then let the script figure out what to do based on the particular date?